# Prove that $K(it)\ne 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $ K $ be the exponential function (commonly $e ^ x$, since it hasn't been defined that way yet). If $ 0 <t <2 \pi $, show that $K(it)\ne 1$.

We have already defined the inverse, which is $ P (t) $ (commonly, the function $ \ln t $).

My attempt is based on reasoning by absurdity, and assuming that $ K (it) = 1 $, then evaluating $ P $ on both sides, $ it = P (K (it)) = P (1) = 0 $, but this happens if $ t = 0 $, but it is absurd since $ t> 0 $. Is my proof correct?

Defining the functions $ K (x) $ and $ P (x) $, $ K (x) = e ^ x $ and $ P (x) = \ln x $, furthermore, all the basic properties of both are known. Also, $ K (ix) = \cos (x) + i \sin (x) $, for $ x \in \Bbb R $.

Comment: Without knowing how you are defining $K$ is it not possible to answer.

Comment: It really depends on what you know about $K$ and $P$. I assume you've already proved that $P(1)=0$, but, I think that $P(x)$ is defined only when $x>0$ (that is $P=(K:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow (0,+\infty))^{-1}$ therefore you can't say that $it=P(K(it))$, unless you've already proved something that allows to write this.

Comment: That's what I thought, let's make it easier, I don't like to take $ K (x) = e ^ x $ or $ P (x) = \ln x $,, because we have not yet proven that these functions coincide. But, can we say that for complex numbers, $ \ln (e ^ {it}) = it $ or not? @Tuvasbien

Comment: Complex logarithm are a bit more complicated than the usual $\log$, in fact there is no $\log$ defined on $\mathbb{C}^*$, the problem being that $\exp:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^*$ is not one-to-one. You can still defined something which comes close to it, bot not such that $\log(e^{it})=it$ for all $t$.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. That was my question, for those functions with complex numbers. Any hints to do the exercise? @Tuvasbien

Comment: As previously said, we can't help you if you don't provide more details and context about how $K$ and $P$ are defined, and what are known about these functions.

Comment: i edit my question :). @Tuvasbien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there exists $t\in(0,2\pi)$ such that $K(it)=1$, then $\cos(t)+i\sin(t)=1$. Taking the real part and the imaginary part of this equality gives $\cos(t)=1$ and $\sin(t)=0$. There is no solutions in $(0,2\pi)$ for the first equation $\cos(t)=1$, therefore there is no solutions at all to $K(it)=0$ in $(0,2\pi)$.